# Delete first row from SQLITE table in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-delete

Its a simple question, how can I just delete the first line from a table without having to give a search criteria.
Normaly it is:

```
c.execute('DELETE FROM name_table WHERE tada=?', (tadida,))
```

I just want to delete first row. Not having the WHERE part. The reason is that I want to create a FIFO table (or stack) add from the bottom and delete from the top.
I can do this by keeping track of time and date or giving the rows a ID. But I would prefer the described method.
Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to delete first row

SQL tables have no inherent ordering, so there is no defined concept of *first* row, unless a column (or a set of columns) is specified for ordering.

Assuming that you do have an ordering colum, say `id`, you can use `limit` to restrict which row should be deleted:

```
delete from mytable order by id limit 1
```

This removes the record that has the smallest `id` from the table.

Comment: @seine: if you want to delete the "latest" row then `order by id desc limit 1`.

Comment: Sqlite only accepts `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` for `DELETE` when built with a specific non-standard [compile time option](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit) that also requires creating a custom version of the sqlite3.c amalgamation source file.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you use a [custom version of sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit), you can't use `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` with `DELETE`.

If your version of sqlite wasn't built with that option (Some OS-distributed ones are, some aren't), and building and installing a copy with it is beyond your comfort level, an alternative, assuming a column named `id` is used for ordering, with the smallest value of `id` being the oldest record:

```sql
DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE id = (SELECT min(id) FROM yourtable);
```